# Facebook login app for site avaiable only through VPN URL:10.0.0

Tags: facebook, url, oauth

I am developing a site that I connect to using VPN

the site url now is: http://10.0.5.253

I would like to test if facebook login will work.

I've tried adding url to "Valid OAuth redirect URIs".
I've also tried setting up a "test app"

It is not an intranet site - it will have a public domain when finished.

Comment: Set up a domain that resolves to that IP on your local machine, f.e. via the `hosts` file – and then use that domain in your app settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @CBroe for the idea.

To the hosts file I added

10.0.5.253 notrealdomain.com www.notrealdomain.com

And then I could set up an facebook app with no problems.